# Remove implicit strings concatenation in python files

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove implicit concatenation from all these examples.

```
my_string = (
    'My '
    'Multi-line '
    'String'
)

my_string = ('My ' 'Multi-line ' 'String')


my_string = ('My ' +
    'Multi-line '
    'String')
```

I want to be sure not to have any strings which are implicitly concatenated in my scripts. I want them to be concatenated either with `+` or inside a same quote group.

I've tried many things but I often catch false-positives like `f('a', 'b')`.

To make it clear, I'd like a way to auto modify python file and make them PEP 3126 compliant.

Comment: `my_string` is already `'My Multi-line String'`, so I can't see the point in your question...

Comment: If you mean to automatically update some code in order to replace strings defined that way by a one-line equivalent, it might be good to make that clearer in your question. Also, note that these aren't multiline strings, as they don't contain any `\n`. It might also be good to share what you tried, even if it doesn't work as well as you'd like.

Comment: I've tried to clarify my question.

Comment: I'm wondering what the reason behind this is. Do you use some tool that complains about implicit concatenation of strings?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a tool which can't handle implicitly concatenated strings.

Comment: You write about "strings which are concatenated with parentheses", but the parentheses play no role (other than extending the statement over multiple lines) in the concatenation; adjacent string literals are concatenated also without parentheses.

Comment: Your requirement is inconsistent - once you write "I want them to be concatenated either with `+` or inside a same quote group", at another place you write "To get simple one line only strings".

Comment: @Armali To make it clear, I just want a way to auto fix issues related to PEP 3126.

Comment: Referring to so-called _issues_ related to the rejected PEP 3126 doesn't make it clear **how** you want to _make them PEP 3126 compliant_. Just write what you want and don't write what you don't want, and don't write different things at different places in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but you can replace newlines with the `.replace()` method.

```py
my_string = (
    'My \n'
    'Multi-line \n'
    'String'
)
my_string = my_string.replace('\n','')
print(my_string)
```

converts from:

```py
My 
Multi-line 
String
```

results:

```py
My Multi-line String
```

Comment: The strings given as examples in the OP's code don't contain any \n, so introducing some in the litteral string and removing them afterwards doesn't really make sense.

Comment: While I agree that their example doesn't show any \n, it's what their asking for with their explanation in words. Showing a possible solution may help them move forward.

Comment: I agree, I could have phrased my question better. The thing is I want to convert all strings concatenated with `()` instead of `+` into simple strings (not on multiple lines)